# Pandas: group by index value, then calculate quantile?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame indexed on the `month` column (set using `df = df.set_index('month')`, in case that's relevant):

```
             org_code  ratio_cost   
month
2010-08-01   1847      8.685939     
2010-08-01   1848      7.883951     
2010-08-01   1849      6.798465     
2010-08-01   1850      7.352603     
2010-09-01   1847      8.778501
```

I want to add a new column called `quantile`, which will assign a quantile value to each row, based on the value of its `ratio_cost` for that month.

So the example above might look like this:

```
             org_code  ratio_cost   quantile
month
2010-08-01   1847      8.685939     100 
2010-08-01   1848      7.883951     66.6 
2010-08-01   1849      6.798465     0  
2010-08-01   1850      7.352603     33.3
2010-09-01   1847      8.778501     100
```

How can I do this? I've tried this:

```
df['quantile'] = df.groupby('month')['ratio_cost'].rank(pct=True)
```

But I get `KeyError: 'month'`.

**UPDATE**: I can reproduce the bug.

Here is my CSV file: http://pastebin.com/raw/6xbjvEL0

And here is the code to reproduce the error:

```
df = pd.read_csv('temp.csv')
df.month = pd.to_datetime(df.month, unit='s')
df = df.set_index('month')
df['percentile'] = df.groupby(df.index)['ratio_cost'].rank(pct=True)
print df['percentile']
```

I'm using Pandas 0.17.1 on OSX.

Comment: try `df['quantile'] = df.groupby(df.index)['ratio_cost'].rank(pct=True)` or  `df['quantile'] = df.groupby(level=0)['ratio_cost'].rank(pct=True)`

Comment: Thanks. I tried just `print df.groupby(level=0)` but it gives me `raise ValueError`. Same with `df.groupby(df.index)`.

Comment: Ah, the month column is a datetime - is that a problem? I've updated the question to show what it produces.

Comment: Thanks, but that's what I originally tried, it's in the question...

Comment: It's actually the `.rank()` call that is producing the error - see update.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You have to [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) before [`rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.rank.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('http://pastebin.com/raw/6xbjvEL0')

df.month = pd.to_datetime(df.month, unit='s')
df = df.set_index('month')

df = df.sort_index()

df['percentile'] = df.groupby(df.index)['ratio_cost'].rank(pct=True)
print df['percentile'].head()

month
2010-08-01    0.2500
2010-08-01    0.6875
2010-08-01    0.6250
2010-08-01    0.9375
2010-08-01    0.7500
Name: percentile, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

a quantile looks at the distribution of the ratio cost and find the 95% percentile region.   you calculate the quantile by calculating the q_cutoff value.   The resulting values are then masked.

```
month=['2010-08-01','2010-08-01','2010-08-01','2010-08-01','2010-09-01']
org_code=[1847,1848,1849,1850,1847]
ratio_cost=[8.685939,7.883951,6.798465,7.352603,8.778501] 
df=pd.DataFrame({'month':month,'org_code':org_code,'ratio_cost':ratio_cost})

q_cutoff = df['ratio_cost'].quantile(0.95)
mask=df['ratio_cost'] < q_cutoff
trimmed_df=df[mask]

 print(trimmed_df)
```